# Jenkins command to get number of builds in queue

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-cli

I am trying to get the number of builds in the Jenkins Build Queue.

May I know the Jenkins command to get the number of builds running in the queue ?

Answer (score 21):

See Jenkins' [Remote access API.](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API)

Access the API description with:

```
  http://<Your Jenkins>/api/
```

and the actual data with:

```
  http://<Your Jenkins>/api/xml
```

The Build queue has its own separate API:

```
  http://<Your Jenkins>/queue/api/
```

with its data:

```
  http://<Your Jenkins>/queue/api/xml
```

Alternatively you can use `json` if you prefer that format, just replace `xml` to `json` in the URL:

```
  http://<Your Jenkins>/queue/api/json
```

Answer (score 7):

That's easy to do with [Jenkins Script Console](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+Script+Console):

```
println Hudson.instance.queue.items.length
// => 2
```

Also that's possible to execute groovy script remotely. For example, from command line:

```
$ curl -u username:password -d "script=println Hudson.instance.queue.items.length" jenkins_url/scriptText
2
```

**Note**: user with specified *username* should have access to Jenkins Script Console.

Comment: Note in more recent versions the call is now `Jenkins.instance.queue.items.size()`, or if you're calling it from a script, `jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.queue.items.size()`

Answer (score 6):

Here is a shell script implementation of the mentioned Jenkins REST API

```
_queuesize=$(curl -s -k -m 60 http://${yourjenkinsserver}:8180/jenkins/queue/api/xml 2>/dev/null | grep -c '<item>')
if [[ -z "${_queuesize}" ]]; then
  _queuesize=0;
fi
```

Comment: For me I had to remove the "jenkins" from the url: http://${yourjenkinsserver}:8180/queue/api/xml

Answer (score 4):

This single bash variable definition using the awesome "jq" utility was all I needed to get the queue length:

```
  QUEUE_SIZE=$(curl -s -k http://<your-jenkins-here>/queue/api/json | jq '.items | length')
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: How do we get the job name?

Answer (score 1):

Just slightly related, but if you looking for the queue size for monitoring, there is a jenkins plugin for munin which does that (and some others too):

https://gallery.munin-monitoring.org/plugins/munin-contrib/jenkins_/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try [Jenkins API in Python](https://python-jenkins.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html).

```
get_jobs()
  Get list of jobs running.
  Each job is a dictionary with ‘name’, ‘url’, and ‘color’ keys.
Returns:    list of jobs, [ { str: str} ]
```