# How to send warning email when build queue exceeds a particular length?

Tags: jenkins

I manage a Jenkins server with a few hundred projects in the whole ecosystem. Many of the projects rely on upstream servers, that, unfortunately, are not always responsive. When I have a lag on these servers, my build queue can get to 10 or more. Is there a plugin or setting to send a warning email when the build queue exceeds a particular length?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have been unable to find a plugin that does this, but you can query Jenkins for the information as detailed here: [Jenkins command to get number of builds in queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31337951/jenkins-command-to-get-number-of-builds-in-queue).

If you have a Jenkins slave available you could set up a job that runs every 15 minutes and just hit each of the other Jenkins servers with the API call to get build queue counts (this is easy if you have just one master and many slaves.)

If you wanted to stay completely outside of Jenkins (not add another job to the mix) you could write a script to poll the Jenkins API for the information. You could then run that script under, say, a 15 minute (or some other relevant time step) timer using cron (or windows scheduled task). Admittedly then you have to dedicate some resources to running this job.

It looks like you could use python to get the build queue and check the length of the returned list. [get_queue_info()](https://python-jenkins.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#jenkins.Jenkins.get_queue_info)

I haven't mucked about with the Jenkins API much myself so I'm not sure offhand exactly what the script would need, but it should be simple enough once you dig into it.